# Fazer um foreach que não repita o mesmo dados

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

Tenho esse foreach, em uma tabela com mais de 5000 registros. Existe apenas 6 tipos de unidade de negócio. Gostaria que no foreach e na linq, quando aparecesse um tipo de UN, ele carrega e depois não mais repita ele, ou seja, ele carrega outro diferente e assim por diante, de forma que o resultado venha somente 6 registros. Abaixo meu foreach.

```
foreach (var _idmotivo in monta_arvore)
            {
                _listaUnidade = db.Apresentacao
                                .Where(un => un.Codigo_Unidade_Negocio == _idmotivo.Codigo_Unidade_Negocio)
                                .Select(u => new MontaArvoreAcao
                                {
                                    Unidade_Negocio = u.Unidade_Negocio,
                                    Codigo_Unidade_Negocio = u.Codigo_Unidade_Negocio
                                }).ToList().OrderBy(o => o.Unidade_Negocio);
            }
```

Comment: Não entendi em qual você quer fazer. É no monta_arvore ou no _listaUnidade?

Comment: No _listaUnidade, pois ele me trás vários nomes e não gostaria de ver repetidos. Usei distinct e nada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer usando o `GroupBy`.

```
_listaUnidade = db.Apresentacao
                                .Where(un => un.Codigo_Unidade_Negocio == _idmotivo.Codigo_Unidade_Negocio)
                                .Select(u => new MontaArvoreAcao
                                {
                                    Unidade_Negocio = u.Unidade_Negocio,
                                    Codigo_Unidade_Negocio = u.Codigo_Unidade_Negocio
                                })
                                .GroupBy(x=>x.Unidade_Negocio)
                                .Select(x=>x.First()
                                .ToList().OrderBy(o => o.Unidade_Negocio);
```

Comment: Deixa-me explicar. Dessa forma só trás um e não é isso que eu quero, exemplo. Eu tenho um total de 6 motivos. Para cada motivo, eu posso ter um ou mais UN e também são 6 UN no total. Então, há Motivos que pode trazer 3 UN, outros podem trazer 2, 4 ou mais ou menos. É isso que eu necessito. Porém, um motivo pode ter 300 Genéricos, aí só quero que mostre apenas 1(Genérico) e o mesmo para MIP, RX e etc....

Comment: A minha dificuldade está no meu where. Vou fazer outro post pensando apenas no where e como trazer cada UN referente ao ID passado. O resposta do Diego Zanardo está correta. Fiz um pouco diferente, mas é a mesma coisa postada pelo Diego Zanardo.